How to serialize Dictionary of objects using message pack
I'm looking into serializing ideally any class into a binary. As the good old BinaryFormatter being deprecated I'm looking into MessagePack - however it seems there are cases with which it is struggling.
public class Foo
{
  public Dictionary<string, object> Bar { get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Dictionary<string, object>() };
foo.Bar.Add("binding", JObject.Parse(@"{
  ""source"": ""EventRegistrationFormDataSource"",
  ""inputs"": {
    ""sourceType"": {
      ""value"": ""msevtmgt_event""
    }
  },
  ""outputPath"": ""msevtmgt_description"",
  ""outputType"": ""memo""
}"));

var options = TypelessContractlessStandardResolver.Options;
MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(foo, options);

The error being below. I was playing with different combination of resolvers, however all seems to fail on this error. Any idea ?
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer', on 'MessagePack.Formatters.NonGenericListFormatter`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'. 

Stack Trace: 
    RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeType inst)
    RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
    RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
    DynamicGenericResolverGetFormatterHelper.GetFormatter(Type t)
    FormatterCache`1.cctor()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    FormatterResolverExtensions.Throw(TypeInitializationException ex)
    Serialize(Byte[][], Object[], MessagePackWriter&, JProperty, MessagePackSerializerOptions)
    <4 more frames...>
    DictionaryFormatterBase`5.Serialize(MessagePackWriter& writer, TDictionary value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    Serialize(Byte[][], Object[], MessagePackWriter&, Foo, MessagePackSerializerOptions)
    AnonymousSerializableFormatter`1.Serialize(MessagePackWriter& writer, T value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    MessagePackSerializer.Serialize[T](MessagePackWriter& writer, T value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)


You might need a formatter for JObject, see https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/515

Why are you using JSON inside MessagePack?

@AlexanderPetrov - I guess why not ? :)  For context - I'm trying to write generic wrapper for redis cache serialization which used to use BinaryFormatter, and I don't see all the edge cases consumers might have invented nor I do have power to change contracts on consumer side.

Based on Progman's link - https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp/issues/515 - the answer is to create your own formatter that would convert JObject to IDictionary and back. This isn't supported in MsgPack vanilla as it would require MsgPack to include reference to Newtonsoft.Json. Posting code snippet as although the idea is valid the solution in the github is little bit outdated (for older version of MsgPack).
Create a formatter:
public sealed class JObjectFormatter : IMessagePackFormatter<JObject>
{
    public JObject Deserialize(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // ideally this would be passed via DI
        var formatter = CompositeResolver.Create(TypelessContractlessStandardResolver.Instance)
            .GetFormatter<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        var dictionary = formatter!.Deserialize(ref reader, options);
        return JObject.FromObject(dictionary);
    }

    public void Serialize(ref MessagePackWriter writer, JObject value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // ideally this would be passed via DI
        var formatter = CompositeResolver.Create(TypelessContractlessStandardResolver.Instance)
            .GetFormatter<IDictionary<string, object>>()!;

        var dictionary = value.ToDictionary();
        formatter.Serialize(ref writer, dictionary, options);
    }
}

When serializing make sure to pass it to MsgPack options:
var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard
    .WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.TrustedData)
    .WithResolver(
         CompositeResolver.Create(
             new[] { new JObjectFormatter() },
             new IFormatterResolver[] {
                 ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance,
                 TypelessContractlessStandardResolver.Instance }));

MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(..., options);

Some helper methods for tranistion between JObject and IDictionary<string, object>:
public static class JsonConversionExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this JObject json)
    {
        var propertyValuePairs = json.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()!;
        ProcessJObjectProperties(propertyValuePairs);
        ProcessJArrayProperties(propertyValuePairs);
        return propertyValuePairs;
    }

    private static void ProcessJObjectProperties(IDictionary<string, object> propertyValuePairs)
    {
        var objectPropertyNames = (from property in propertyValuePairs
                                   let propertyName = property.Key
                                   let value = property.Value
                                   where value is JObject
                                   select propertyName).ToList();

        objectPropertyNames.ForEach(propertyName => propertyValuePairs[propertyName] = ToDictionary((JObject)propertyValuePairs[propertyName]));
    }

    private static void ProcessJArrayProperties(IDictionary<string, object> propertyValuePairs)
    {
        var arrayPropertyNames = (from property in propertyValuePairs
                                  let propertyName = property.Key
                                  let value = property.Value
                                  where value is JArray
                                  select propertyName).ToList();

        arrayPropertyNames.ForEach(propertyName => propertyValuePairs[propertyName] = ToArray((JArray)propertyValuePairs[propertyName]));
    }

    public static object[] ToArray(this JArray array)
    {
        return array.ToObject<object[]>()!.Select(ProcessArrayEntry).ToArray();
    }

    private static object ProcessArrayEntry(object value)
    {
        if (value is JObject)
        {
            return ToDictionary((JObject)value);
        }
        if (value is JArray)
        {
            return ToArray((JArray)value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}

